# convert into string functions?

Tags: c++, stream, inputstream

Does anyone know how to take this function into strings instead of print to CMD??

```
    printf("RECV: [%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d] TRADE [symbol:%s last:%0.*f]\n",
    pUpdate->lastDateTime.hour, pUpdate->lastDateTime.minute, pUpdate-    >lastDateTime.second, pUpdate->lastDateTime.milliseconds,
    Helper::ConvertString(pUpdate->symbol.symbol, _countof(pUpdate->symbol.symbol)).c_str(),
    pUpdate->lastPrice.precision, pUpdate->lastPrice.price);
```

like

last price,Symbol,and a Time function that combines (pUpdate->lastDateTime.hour, pUpdate->lastDateTime.minute, pUpdate->lastDateTime.second, pUpdate->lastDateTime.milliseconds) that will display a string of i.e. 09:09:09:0999???
I posted earlier when I thought I had the solution, but it failed. I woud like see if anyone can come up with a better solution. function streams data. here is what I came up with.

//If we get a update for a symbol we update corresponding sli....

```
    }
string synbol1;
string  sli1;// sli1..2..etc will hold a single symbol
string sli2;
string sli3;
string sli4;
/*virtual*/ void Streamer::OnATStreamTradeUpdate(LPATQUOTESTREAM_TRADE_UPDATE pUpdate)
{

    Helper::ConvertString(pUpdate->symbol.symbol, _countof(pUpdate->symbol.symbol)).c_str() == synbol1;


    if (synbol1 == sli1){
        pUpdate->lastDateTime.hour, pUpdate->lastDateTime.minute, pUpdate->lastDateTime.second, pUpdate->lastDateTime.milliseconds,
            pUpdate->lastPrice.precision, pUpdate->lastPrice.price;
                         }

    else if (synbol1 == sli2){
        pUpdate->lastDateTime.hour, pUpdate->lastDateTime.minute, pUpdate->lastDateTime.second, pUpdate->lastDateTime.milliseconds,
            pUpdate->lastPrice.precision, pUpdate->lastPrice.price;
    }
    else if (synbol1 == sli3)
    {
        pUpdate->lastDateTime.hour, pUpdate->lastDateTime.minute, pUpdate->lastDateTime.second, pUpdate->lastDateTime.milliseconds,
            pUpdate->lastPrice.precision, pUpdate->lastPrice.price;
    }
    else if (synbol1 == sli4)
    {
        pUpdate->lastDateTime.hour, pUpdate->lastDateTime.minute, pUpdate->lastDateTime.second, pUpdate->lastDateTime.milliseconds,
            pUpdate->lastPrice.precision, pUpdate->lastPrice.price;
    }
```

Comment: I am a native programmer of C. Therefore can you explain why have you written inside body of if's and else if's same statement. I mean if each condition executes same thing then why use conditions. Second thing, why have you separated them with commas, i.e. what does the statements inside if-else body exactly perform.

Comment: I was just taking a stab at this from just looking at the original function. as I checked for (sprintf) but the unit_t is incon. with char.<error> If the Symbol(synbol1) matches a else statement it updates Last and adds a time(hour ..min ..etc)   sli1 will have its own last and time...and sli2..and so on.....